# Lord's Prayer: Thy will be done. Sequence, grammatical, and theological considerations

Tags: grammar, linguistics, lords-prayer

Typically one finds in English renditions:

> Thy will be done on Earth as it is in Heaven. (Matthew 6:10 KJV)

But a more rigorous translation which also follows the Greek word order:

> Let come the Kingdom of you, let come about the Will of you, as in Heaven also upon Earth. ([Source](https://www.catholic.com/qa/why-isnt-the-our-father-translated-exactly-as-jesus-prayed-it))

Getting to my question:

Does this wording imply a role for Christians? Does "let come about the will of you" entail any human agency other than supplication? I.e., does this imply the realization of "The Will of you" to any degree through us?

Comment: @agarza Nice touch - vastly improved. Thanks

Comment: Hi, um - are not all Christians born again? Are you perhaps referring to Arminianists in your question detail? Or Pentecostal Christians, perhaps? If someone presumes you are referring to something other than just being a ‘genuine’ Christian, they’ll avoid answering your question... If that’s all you mean - a regenerate Christian - then perhaps remove the caps and put it in brackets to broaden the range of potential answerers? I’ll leave answering the question to linguists, although personally I don’t see a difference in the ‘flowy’ vs. ‘heavy standard’ English versions off the bat.

Comment: @AshleyRoberts Excellent idea, fixed. The distinction I was driving at is between "be done" and "let come." While both appear to be subjunctive, the former seems to imply definitive on the part of God, whereas the latter looks like asking God to allow it. The question then becomes is God himself to do it in response to the supplication, or is God being asked to enable us to bring it about. Kind regards,

Comment: (I suspect that a lot of the ‘us vs. God’ dynamic in this (if indeed that’s your thinking) can be resolved if one considers what time looks like from the perspective of eternity, namely just a single point; a moment if you will. So from our perspective, we live out our days, we think this and choose that, and Paul urges us, e.g., to be reconciled to God. From the eternal perspective, the entire course of the universe is like a piece of pottery, made by God. Everything exists at the point of creation. Thus we have “The Book of Life”, e.g., with its list of names, existing since the beginning.)

Comment: Ah.. yes I see where you’re going with that! Hopefully I didn’t speak under you there in the previous quip!

Comment: @Andrew Peter There is on this site a question which I think you may find is related to yours. It is "What does 'be done' mean in Matthew 6:10 'your will be done on earth as it is in heaven"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only dare to respond to this because it is tagged with grammar and linguistics. I am fairly comfortable with that.

Here are the lines you are asking about.

**Mt 6:10**

> Γενηθἠτω τὸ θέλημἀ σου, ὡς ἐν οὐρανῷ καὶ ἐπὶ γῆς
>
> Be the will of you, as in heaven even on earth

That is a terrible translation, but it is as literal as I can get. Good translations can be found in just about any English Bible.

Writing in prose, the prayer asks that the Father's will be done even (καὶ) on earth just as (ὡς) it is done in heaven.

Your question: does it imply human agency?

Since the prayer asks that the Father's will be done on earth in the same way (ὡς) as it is done in heaven, I see no room for human agency. Human agency has no role for the Father's will being done in heaven, and the prayer asks that it be done on earth, in the same way as it is done in heaven.

Comment: I agree with you. Subsequent translations, as all subsequent discourse is susceptible to revisionism.  Kind regards,

Comment: Enjoy your time here among all the questions and answers. Be well!

Answer (score 1):

When praying to Avinu (Our Father), consider [Psalm 149] "He does the will of those who fear Him" ( רְצֽוֹן יְרֵאָיו יַֽעֲשֶׂה ), and through those who fear YHVH (like King David), רְצֽוֹנְךָ Retson-kha (Your-Will) is done, as stated in [Psalm 40] "God, I desired to do Your will" (לַֽעֲשׂוֹת רְצֽוֹנְךָ אֱלֹהַי חָפָצְתִּי).

All Promises established in heaven (through prayer & blessings by those who fear YHVH) will eventually be done (through objects which serve YHVH on earth) as stated כָל חֶפְצִי אֶֽעֱשֶֽׂ in [Isaiah 46:10].

The dynamic of Our Father's Will in answering prayers is [1] Confession (not bribery through sacrifice) [2] Faith in His Will [3] Allowing any form of matter in existence (particles, water, fire, stars, sediments, plants, metals, animals, humans) which all belong to YHVH Elohim to be used to accomplish His Will for those who remembered Elohim & feared Him as their Father, as stated in [Psalm 50].